# Как убрать программу в диспетчере запущенных программ?

Tags: java, android

Я закрываю программу
через  `System.exit(0);`
но программа все равно висит в фоне в  диспетчере  запущенных программ как там убрать?

Answer (score 4):

`finishAndRemoveTask();`

сработало идеально для меня !